# Place title inside the chart of LighningChartJS

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

When I add title to chart it's creating padding above the chart. How to make the title appear inside chart?

```
chart.setTitle("title");
```

I tried padding on chart, this one hides the title:

```
   chart.setTitle("title").setPadding({
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: -36,
            left: 0
        }).setMouseInteractions(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.0.1/classes/ChartXY.html#setTitlePosition

```
ChartXY.setTitlePosition("series-left-top")
```

Comment: hi , yea I saw documentation and got that.